# Android Studio and Firebase: Synchronization Issue in Online Chess Game After Several Moves

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to develop an online chess game in Android Studio with Firebase integration. I've implemented an AsyncTask to listen to Firebase and determine whether the other user has made a move. The code functions well for the first two turns for each user, but then, on the fifth turn, the synchronization ceases to function. What could be causing this issue?

I'm attempting to utilize an AsyncTask in my code, as shown below:

`public class RivalMoveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private Board _board;
private chessBoard _chess;

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    // Fetch the rival's move in the background
    return _board.getRivalMove();
}

public RivalMoveTask(Board board, chessBoard chess) {
    _board = board;
    _chess = chess;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String rivalMove) {
    super.onPostExecute(rivalMove);
    if (rivalMove != null) {
        // Update the UI with the rival's move
        _chess.changeRivalMove(rivalMove);
    }
}
```

}`
The getRivalMove function listens to the database and returns the rival's move, while the changeRivalMove function takes the rival's move obtained from getRivalMove and updates it in the UI.